# Return back from youtube to my android app

Tags: android, android-intent, youtube

In my app, on a particular button click, the youtube application starts and some video gets played. This is the code for the same.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:0ee3R3tfdd4"));
startActivity(i);
```

Is it possible to close the youtube app when the video is finished and return back gracefully to my app (without the user pressing the back button) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, it's not possible.

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:0ee3R3tfdd4"));
startActivity(i);
```

Using this code you are open a third party youtube application, So you don't have any type of control over it.

You have to press Back Button to coming back to your application. Or integrate Your own `VideoView` in your application for display youtube video.

Comment: I have tried videoview but somehow it doesn't work.. So, have used this code as the last option..

Answer (score 0):

That obviously has to be done in the youtube app which you cannot do. However, if you play the video in your own activity/fragment using a video view, you can do it.